# How can I associate sections with classes in a config file?

Tags: python, dependency-injection, configuration

Suppose I have a program to retrieve information on different types of animals. I have the animal types represented in named tuples, which I construct from a config file:

**config.ini**

```
[Cat]
limb_count = 4
size_class = Small
```

**animals.py**

```
AnimalData = namedtuple('Animal', 'type limb_count size_class')
```

Now, I scrape data for each animal from a different site, so my `AnimalStatsRepository` is set up something like this:

```
class AnimalStatsRepository(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._queries_by_animal = {
            'Cat': CatQuery(),
            'Dog': DogQuery(),
            'Zebra': ZebraQuery()
        }    

    def get_birthrate(self, animal):
        return self._queries_by_animal[animal.type].get_birthrate()
        # And also do database stuff that's not relevant to the question
```

I want to be able to set the `_queries_by_animal` dictionary at runtime based on whatever animal data I've read from a config file. So something like:

```
class AnimalStatsRepository(object):
    def __init__(self, animals_data):
        self._queries_by_animal = {} 
        for animal in animals_data:
            self._queries_by_animal[animal.type] = ??
```

I can probably get what I want with some evil reflection hacking. But is there a better way to approach this?

Answer (score 0):

A factory method can be used to create the proper query from the text in the config file. An implementation might look like this:

```
def animal_query_factory(animal_name):
    if animal_name == 'Cat':
        return CatQuery()
    if animal_name == 'Dog':
        return DogQuery()
    raise NotImplementedError('Unable to handle animal: {}'.format(animal_name))
```